# Meaning of お願い出します

Tags: meaning

Recently I've been listening to some Japanese radio stations online. I heard somebody say

> お願い出します

a couple of times. I'm now hearing it sometimes in other places.

Can somebody tell me what it means? I can get search engine results with pages that use it but rikaichan doesn't translate it as a phrase, just the two components.
Could somebody explain it to me please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like you're hearing it incorrectly. The phrase you want is お願{ねが}い致{いた}します. 致します is the humble form of します, so it's really just a more polite way to say お願いします.

Comment: Yes, I believe you are right. This link here which uses お願い出します http://lang-8.com/275973/journals/1309935 has a comment underneath where somebody corrects them to お願い致します

Comment: I can understand why one might want to think that お願い出します could be right as 出す is often used as a suffix like that, but it's just not used that way *with お願い*. お願い致します is a VERY common expression and I would say with virtually 100% certainty that it's the right interpretation your case.